discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired when necessary privileged intents enabled
I'm making a bot for the redeeming of giftcodes for a game with discord.py, selenium and google sheets. When i try to run the code I get this error while I have the member and message privileged intents enabled:
[2024-09-26 09:21:30] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hylke\OneDrive\Documenten\Java Projecten\Python Whiteout test\whiteoutbotv2.py", line 140, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 858, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 787, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\hylke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 711, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

My code:
import os
import discord
import asyncio
import gspread
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD_ID = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD_ID')
GOOGLE_SHEET_ID = os.getenv('GOOGLE_SHEET_ID')
GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = 'RedeemListTest'
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE')

# Set up intents and bot
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guilds = True
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
# error comes from the last line which is: bot.run(TOKEN)


How would I fix this?

Please read the error, the solution is literally written there.

As already mentioned, the solution is in the traceback of your error:
Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

I tried every combination of enabled and disabled but that didn't work. After carefully looking over my code i realized that I didn't need it anymore as it is probably a holdover from a previous version. So solved but unsolved.
